# How to avoid netcat from blocking, when using it as a client to send a file or pipelining output?

Tags: php, sockets, netcat

When I use netcat to talk to a server listening at a TCP socket using an input file or pipelining, the client then hangs and I cant send any input. Any idea how can I make it **not block?**
At the of this question there's the code of the 'server' I'm using for this, it runs on PHP.

If I do from terminal this:

```
netcat 192.168.1.10 3320
```

Then I can talk to the server undefinetely, it just echoes back every line I send (LF).

But If I do this:

```
netcat 192.168.1.10 3320 < file
or
echo "Something" | netcat 192.168.1.10 3320
```

Then the server returns the contents of the file, but I can't communicate anymore with netcat. The [client] process just blocks.  Once the server is shutdown, then the client unblocks and everything written on console after the line above is interpreted by shell.

I have been looking for an answer with no success, but from what I have read, this is an issue with netcat. It appears to treat the connection as closed once it sees an EOF.

I have attempted the waiting option and keeps blocking:

```
netcat -q -1 192.168.1.10 3320 < file
```

No success.
What I am attemting to do is to do is to send the content of a file with netcat and then be able to send messages using the same console.

The 'server':

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
$address = "192.168.1.10";
$port = 3320;
$server_users = 3; 
$mysock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$bind_result = socket_bind($mysock,$address, $port) or die("Could not bind to address\n"); 
$listen_result = socket_listen($mysock, $server_users)  or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
$client = socket_accept($mysock) or die("Could not accept the connection to socket\n");

do {
    $input = socket_read($client,1024,PHP_BINARY_READ);
    echo $input;
} while(TRUE);
?>
```

If you need to now, I run it in terminal using:

```
$ php -q server.php
```

Comment: `cat /path/to/file | netcat 192.168.1.10 3320 > /dev/null 2>&1 &`? I don't quite understand the problem/what you are trying to achieve here. What is the practical application of this server?

Comment: Oh you hinted me in the right direction, Thanks! This is what I used:
    cat /path/to/file - | netcat 102.168.1.10 3320
Maybe you could help my learning further by explaining what you intended to do with your line (I don't understand the 2>&1 &).

As for the purpose, this is a simple server im writing for my mobille phones, I want to send data in files and then send commands manually.

But mostly I'm learning

Comment: `2>&1` redirects (`>&`) STDERR (`2`) to STDOUT (`1`). The final `&` detaches the process from the console so it runs in the background. I think I misunderstood exactly what you wanted, the command I gave would start sending the file to the remote host  and immediately return to the prompt, so you could run other commands in the same console while the file was transferring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I am attemting to do is to do is to send the content of a file
>   with netcat and then be able to send messages using the same console.

There's no console, netcat is just reading from the standard input. If you redirecting a file to it, once it's finished there's nothing else to read.

Try this:

```
(cat file ; cat ) | netcat 192.168.1.10 3320
```

Comment: Thanks, that does similar to what I wrote in the comment of the question